# Prevent Docpad from scanning vendor files (but still copy them)

Tags: docpad

I've got a project which holds third party files (installed with Bower) under src/public/vendor. It seems ever since I added those docpad has gotten considerably slower in generating ./out, no doubt cause it's going over all the vendor files.

I'd like to exclude the vendor files from being interpreted by DocPad, but they should still be copied to ./out.

Is there a built-in way to do this through DocPad or should I simply put the vendor files outside the src directory and have Grunt copy it manually to ./out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is legit and I raised the same a while ago :

https://github.com/bevry/docpad/issues/276

In the end, hypercubed developed the "raw" plugin available through npm :

https://npmjs.org/package/docpad-plugin-raw

Depending on what you provide as options, it can either do a cp or a rsync command.
So it basically what you intend to do with a Grunt task.

Comment: That's great! Though I think I will stick with Grunt myself as I prefer to leave vendor in public, a "raw" folder feels redundant. Still, good that there is a solution for people that don't use Grunt.